# installation of cmake on debian 8

Tags: cmake

I tried to install mcsema on my debian linux but I am stopped by error
Cmake 3.1 or higher is required. You are running 3.0.2.  On debian this is the only version could be installed by apt-get install. Building CMake from sources, I get several errors as well. Does anyone know how to install the latest version of Cmake on Debian 8?

Comment: "I get several errors as well" which are...?

Comment: I removed some of the errors, but now I am stopped by the error: cmake error at cmake/protobuf/ProtobufDownloader.cmake: Error:31: Failed to download protobuf source archive. https://github.com/google/protobuf/archive/v2.6.1.tar.gz' "Unsupported protocol". I have clang, cmake and llvm 3.8 installed on my machine. May I ask how can I remove this problem?

Comment: Please post such information in the question so that it's in plain sight.

Answer (score 1):

Download latests [cmake release](https://cmake.org/download/) and follow the `README.rst` instructions:

> UNIX/Mac OSX/MinGW/MSYS/Cygwin ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>
> You need to have a compiler and a make installed. Run the
>   `bootstrap` script you find in the source directory of CMake. You
>   can use the `--help` option to see the supported options. You may
>   use the `--prefix=<install_prefix>` option to specify a custom
>   installation directory for CMake. You can run the `bootstrap` script
>   from within the CMake source directory or any other build directory of
>   your choice. Once this has finished successfully, run `make` and
>   `make install`.  In summary::
>
> $ ./bootstrap && make && make install

Comment: Thanks. I works. Now when running ./bootstrap build --Release, I am stopped by the error:  "  
I removed some of the errors, but now I am stopped by the error: cmake error at cmake/protobuf/ProtobufDownloader.cmake: Error:31: Failed to download protobuf source archive. github.com/google/protobuf/archive/v2.6.1.tar.gz'; "Unsupported protocol". I have clang, cmake and llvm 3.8 installed on my machine. May I ask how can I remove this problem?

Comment: It solved. Te solution is discussed in mcsema issues page.